# How to pass variables as input to SOAP webservice from command line

Tags: bash, curl, soap

I have a Soap web service to which I need to pass input as username and password to get the response. I am able to get the response from command line (Linux) if I hardcode the values with the below command.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @FILE_NAME URL_OF_THE_SERVICE
```

(FILE_NAME is basically my web service with hardcoded values of username and password)

[image: WEBSERVICE Used]

But I don't want to hardcode any values and wanted to pass them as a parameters. Is there any way I can get the response from web service from command line by passing parameters to the web service?

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper script, which 'generates' the output file with the substituted variables.